# fetch `then()` is executing even if api fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have made a wrapper for fetch something like this, I'm importing this wrapper in components but on failure `catch()` of this wrapper is executing but in the component `then()` function is executing any idea!!

```
 import { SERVER_URL } from '../configs/serverConfig';

  export default function callApi(api_url: string, method = 'get', data = null) {


    opts = {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic VFM0NjA2Omsuc3ZpbTg4',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    if (data) {
      opts.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    return fetchWrapper(api_url, opts);
  }



  function fetchWrapper (api_url: string, opts: any){
    let requestParamObj= {};
    if(opts.method.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'get'){
      requestParamObj = {
        method:opts.method
      }
    }
    else if(opts.method.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'post'){
      requestParamObj = {
        method: opts.method,
        headers: opts.headers,
        body: opts.data
      }
    }


    return (
      fetch(api_url, requestParamObj)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(response => {
          return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('request failed', error);
          return error;
        })
    )
  }
```

I'm calling this in a component something like this

```
    callApi('/someURl', 'GET')
        .then((res) => {
        console.log('this get called even if api fails', res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        //TODO :: error handling at global level
        console.log('Some err', err)
    })
    }
```

Comment: What do you have in your `res` var when it's fail, it can help a lot to know what happen !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're catching the error in the wrapper and returning a value, so the consumer will get the returned value instead of the error.

```js
      fetch(api_url, requestParamObj)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(response => {
          return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('request failed', error);
          throw error;
        })
```

if you replace return error with `throw error` the consumer catch will be returned as expected.

PS: Fetch API will resolve the promise even if you get an error status from the API, it will only trigger the catch on actual JavaScript errors, if you want the promise to be rejected on network/API error responses aswell. you might want to do something like this

```js
function handleErrors (response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + response)
    throw Error(response.statusText)
  }
  return response
}
```

and use

```js
.then(handleErrors)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two things going wrong.

Firstly, the promise `fetch` returns only rejects into `catch` if the request fails due to a network error, or in other words - the request never gets to your server. If you get *any* response, even a HTTP 500, then the promise resolves into `then`.

Secondly, like the other answer mentions, if you `catch` a promise then that converts the promise chain back into a success mode. You need to throw, or return `Promise.reject(value)` to kick the chain back into a failure mode.

Your wrapper would better look like:

```
return (
  fetch(api_url, requestParamObj)
    .catch(error => Promise.reject(error)) // Handle network error
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(response) // Handle error responses HTTP 4XX, 5XX
      } else {
        return response.json() // Return success response HTTP 2XX, 3XX
      }
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` API rejects the promise if

> network error is encountered, although this usually means permissions issues or similar.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

In the following example `ok` will be logged:

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function() {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

`fetch` provides an `ok` flag to check that the response is successful:

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response;
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

[Source](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/)